# Validador de celular em um consulta Rest Api

Tags: c#, asp.net, mvc

Hoje eu uso sistema de envio de SMS para nossos cliente que estão cadastrados no `Tiny ERP`, porém eu estou precisando de um validador para celular para ele conseguir enviar SMS agendados que ficam salvos em um banco local.

O problema é que o sistema aceita registrar números errados ou fixo.
Eu vi no fórum um validador feito em `c#`, porém eu não consigo executar muito bem.

Segue o trecho do validador:

```cs
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(cliente.contatos[0].celularddd) && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(cliente.contatos[0].celularnumero))
{
    var celular = "55" + cliente.contatos[0].celularddd + cliente.contatos[0].celularnumero;
    celular = celular.Replace(" ", String.Empty);//quando vem nesse parâmetro o valor do celular = "5515999999999"
    if ( Convert.ToInt32(celular.Substring(5)) == 9)
    { 
        log.celular_cliente = celular;
```

Quando o sistema chega no `if ( Convert.ToInt32(celular.Substring(5)) == 9)` ele não reconhece o numero 9 e não continua o processo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O método Substring (int startIndex) devolve o resto da cadeia partir da posição indicada (startIndex).

Ver 
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.substring?view=netframework-4.8

Exemplo:

```
"5515999999999".Substring((5)) == "99999999"
```

**Update 1#**

Consulte a documentação de expressões regulares em
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex?view=netframework-4.8

Exemplo de função em c# para validar que começa por 55 e que o 5 digito é um 9.

```
NumeroValido("55(12)94567-8910")
//true

NumeroValido("55(12)14567-8910")
//false


    public static Boolean NumeroValido(string numero)
    {

        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(numero)) return false; //ignora

        Regex regex = new Regex(@"[^\d]"); //expressão regular para excluir todos os caracteres excepto dígitos

        numero = regex.Replace(numero, ""); //remove não digítos

        //@"^55\d\d9" expressão regular de validação

        if (Regex.IsMatch(numero, @"^55\d\d9"))
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"O número {numero} é válido");

            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"O número {numero} é invválido");

            return false;
        };

    }
```

Comment: Entendi, tem um validador que eu possa usar?

Comment: Pode usar regex, sabe as regras da numeração?

Comment: Ah sim, vou testar o regex, obrigado

Comment: Tem um exemplo? pois ele vem de uma APi

Comment: Mostre um exemplo de um número no seu país e explica a sua composição

Comment: No Brasil o celular (12)34567-8910, porem para o envio tem o código do pais que é 55, só que no caso a string vem "5512345678910" e eu preciso que o quinto numero seja 9